# Spotify api not searching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, spotify

I'm working on a project in codecademy that lets you make a playlist through spotify, but when I type something in the search nothing pops out.I assume its something with the spotify api.

I was seeing that spotify changed their endpoints but I'm not really sure. Nothing in the console says any error. Any help?

**Spotify.js**

```
const clientId = '**';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000'
let accessToken;

const Spotify = {
    getAccessToken() {
        if (accessToken){
            return accessToken;
        }

        //check for access token match
        const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
        const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);

        if(accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
            accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
            const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
            //clears params, allowing to grab new access token when it expires
            window.setTimeout(() => accessToken ='', expiresIn * 1000);
            window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
            return accessToken;
        } else {
            const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
            window.location = accessUrl;
        }
    },

    search(term){
        const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(jsonResponse => {
        if (!jsonResponse.tracks){
            return [];
        } 
        return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
            id: track.id,
            name: track.name,
            artist: track.artist[0].name,
            album: track.album.name,
            uri: track.uri
        }))
    })
    },

    savePlayList(name, trackUris){
        if(!name || !trackUris.length){
            return;
        }

        const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`};
        let userId;

        return fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {headers: headers}
        ).then(response => response.json()
        ).then(jsonResponse => {
            userId = jsonResponse.id;
            return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, 
            {
                headers: headers,
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({name: name})
            }).then(response => response.json()
            ).then(jsonResponse => {
                const playListId = jsonResponse.id;
                return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists/${playListId}/tracks`, {
                headers: headers,
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({uris: trackUris})
                })
            })
        })
    }
}

export default Spotify;
```

Comment: check your devTools > network tabs and check your API calls and the response. Maybe you find out the solution via checking the response error of your request.

Answer (score 1):

I found that spotify api changed the json response. I removed the [0] in `artist: track.artist[0].name` to `artist: track.artists.name` and this worked.